# Error Regarding the Title

Tags: android

I have got the Exception on AndroidRunTimeException. . .
It says that the You can not combine Custom titles With other title features.
Can anybudy says why it is occurs ??
My Exceptions in as below :

```
04-26 15:26:12.461: ERROR/BluetoothChat(455): +++ ON CREATE +++
04-26 15:26:12.616: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-26 15:26:12.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.menu/com.menu.volunteer_management.BluetoothChatApp}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features
04-26 15:26:12.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
04-26 15:26:12.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
04-26 15:26:12.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
04-26 15:26:12.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
04-26 15:26:12.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-26 15:26:12.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-26 15:26:12.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-26 15:26:12.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-26 15:26:12.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-26 15:26:12.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-26 15:26:12.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-26 15:26:12.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-26 15:26:12.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features
04-26 15:26:12.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:183)
04-26 15:26:12.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2057)
04-26 15:26:12.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2207)
04-26 15:26:12.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:194)
04-26 15:26:12.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
04-26 15:26:12.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at com.menu.volunteer_management.BluetoothChatApp.onCreate(BluetoothChatApp.java:74)
04-26 15:26:12.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-26 15:26:12.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
04-26 15:26:12.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     ... 11 more
```

Thank You..

Comment: Post the exception and the corresponding code. Otherwise we can't help.

Comment: what is the exact Logcat details, please share.

Comment: See the Edited Question for Exception

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686556/try-to-use-window-featuru-custom-title-but-got-exceptionyou-cannot-combine-custo and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533830/how-to-set-icon-to-title-bar-for-each-activity-in-tablayout

Answer (score 0):

In android 4.0 and later you can not add your custom title in this way get help from this document.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/CustomTitle.html