# Error Regarding the Title

Tags: android, title, custom-titlebar

I have got an AndroidRunTimeException, that says that you cannot combine custom titles with other title features.

Can anybody tell me why it occurs?

Comment: Paste some code causing the error, and a stack trace. Also avoid using tags that are not directly linked with you question.

Comment: We need to look at your AndroidManifest.xml file to help you out here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error Regarding the Title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788420/error-regarding-the-title)