# Need your help related to using tab host with custom title

Tags: android, android-tabhost, custom-titlebar

With reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4534359/1016544) post,  I need your suggestion. I have resolved the displaying of custom title bar using that answer. I have implemented buttons in my title bar along with title text. When I try to set `onclicklistener` on button it gives `NullPointerException` because the custom title bar xml is set using the tab host activity.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `ActionbarSherlock`by Jake Wharton.