# How to make custom title bar for my android application?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Custom Title Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157522/android-custom-title-bar)

I want to make custom title bar for my application for cahnging the color of my applicatin name.How can i do this?

Comment: This is the best example for creating a custom title bar... http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-custom-window-title-in-android/

Comment: [Best example](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-programming-tutorials/creating-a-custom-title-bar/)

Answer (score 1):

Write this thing in your Activity.

```
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.mytitle);
```

And mytitle layout is the xml file which will be shown as title menu.
Following is a small example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/myTitle"
 android:text="custom title bar"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:textColor="@color/titletextcolor"
 android:gravity ="center"/>
```

OR IF YOU ONLY WANT TO WRITE THEN

```
setTitle("Your TITLE");
```

You can make your OWN. Other References [Reference 1](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-programming-tutorials/creating-a-custom-title-bar/), [Reference 2](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam;jsessionid=5424397F3130CE7769FF47DD67742911?recipeId=1584&recipeFrom=ViewTOC).