# Android Custom title bar with parent Style

Tags: android, android-layout

I have set up a custom title bar and it works OK, but before the code is called the default title bar is shown and I don´t want this.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157522/android-custom-title-bar/) someone gives as a solution to define a new style from scratch. It works fine if this custom style has not parent, but if you use a parent style you get this previous title bar shown before mine.

As far as I am using Theme.Light in my app, how can I fix this ? Which parameter should I rewrite in my custom style to remove this previous title bar ??

Thanks !

Comment: please put some code that how you are going to display the custom title bar if you dont have set style with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Theme.Light.NoTitleBar` instead, or use that as a parent for you own theme.

Comment: It does not work. It crashes. Please note that I want to show my custom title bar. What I do not want is the default title bar which is shown while code is called.